# Regex Code for getting only words in title case from a paragraph

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex expression that only returns words in Title Case (where only the first letter is capitalized) from a given sentence or paragraph.

If the paragraph is:

```
France’s last serious attempt at ambitious economic reform, an overhaul of pensions and social security, was in the mid-1990s under President Jacques Chirac.
```

I'd like it to match `France`, `President`, `Jacques` and `Chirac`.

(I'm writing in Python 3)

Comment: Unicode or ASCII only? Which language/tool are you using?

Comment: Using Python 3, UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a word boundary, a capital letter, then as many lowercase letters as follow:

```
\b[A-Z][a-z]+
```

Like this:

```
titleWords = re.findall(r"\b[A-Z][a-z]+", line)
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/imLSyZ).

Note that `+` (at least 1) is preferable to `*` (0  or more) so you don't match single-capital-letter words, like `"I"` and `"A"`.

The word boundary isn't really necessary, but prevents matching camelcase words like `"mySpace"` which shouln't happen in regular text anyway, so you could probably remove `\b` without ill effect.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the regex-flavour, the results may differ.

For PCRE, I suggest:

```
/\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b/
```

Comment: What about `France` from `France's` ?

Comment: Just checked, it works. `\b` is a "word border", and `'` seems to be considered that

Comment: I tested it on [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) and it only seems to match the first word. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Lose the brackets: You don't need them. The entire match is the target

Comment: @john You need to add `g` to the end ("global" flag) to match all occurrences ie `/\b[A-Z][a-z]+/g`

Comment: True, the brackets are not necessary

Comment: @Bohemian - really stupid question, but `line = "France’s last serious attempt at ambitious economic reform, an overhaul of pensions and social security, was in the mid-1990s under President Jacques Chirac."` followed by `matches = re.findall(r"/\b[A-Z][a-z]+/g", line)` returns nothing for me. What stupid mistake did I make this time?

Comment: `matches = re.findall(r"\b[A-Z][a-z]+", line)`

Comment: @john it seems python (with which I'm not familiar) doesn't use slashes like JavaScript. See a [live demo](https://ideone.com/OCKzrg) I created of python extracting the words you want from your sample text

Answer (score 0):

To deal with any language letters, use unicode properties:

```
re.findall(r"\b\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+", inputLine)
```

where

- `\p{Lu}` stands for any uppercase letter in any language
- `\p{Ll}` stands for any lowercase letter in any language